# when present perfect or future in that case

Tags: future-tense

Please let me know when you have received the book or is it better to write
let me know when you will receive it

Is it grammatically correct because in that case the when clause is not a time clause so the  future should be needed

Comment: "when you will receive it" is not correct there.  It refers to an event that is still in the other person's future. You want to know when the book is  in that person's hands, that is, when the person *has received* it.  You can also use the present:  *Please let me know when you receive it.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [future or present with when](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56459/future-or-present-with-when). It's also worth looking at [A sentence in Present tense was understood as future tense.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48757/)